# silly problem with combobox SelectedIndex and selectedValue in c# windows application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, user-controls, combobox

I Have a silly problem with combobox selectedindex.I have a usercontrol(UC) and I place a combobox on it. in UC load event I bind combo to a datatable(or even List) that has 10 rows and then I want to select socond Item but I get an out of range exception.

the fun is when I comment selecting second row and run application combo has **10 Items.**

if I use any thing instead of BindingSource I have prolem.Ho I can Solve That?
thanks

Edit 1) Here is the code:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = dsBase.Tables["MyDt"];
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Desc";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1;
```

**Edit 1)**
Can any body Explain this images?

*Image 1:*
[image: 1]

*Image 2:*
[image: 2]

*Image 3:*

[image: 3]

*Image 4:*

[image: 4]

Comment: How are you doing it ,can you show us the code ?>

Comment: Strange this should work, '**comboBox1.Items**' is this empty ?

Comment: Yes.It's Empty.In the project I ask my freind to test it in another UserControl but he get exception too.

Comment: you sure dsBase.Tables["MyDt"] contains records, coz the above code runs fine at my end

Comment: I Update My Question and upload 4 image.please watch and give your idea.the fun thing is when load complete every thing is fine but in first load SelectedValue is null.thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Long time no see front end applications, but I would say that you need to select the item on the Combo DataBinding event.

BR